# Is the book "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" a good read for Java programmers?

Tags: learning, books

This may be subjective and likely to be closed but I still wanted to know if its really helpfull to read Structure and Interpretation of Computer programs.

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

The book does not use Java. Not that I wanted to learn Java. I am just curious as to know if it be will useful read to be a better programmer and what are the things that I can gain from the book or are their any other alternatives to this book more suited to Java programmers?

Comment: For starters, try not to position yourself as a "java programmer". Or as "whatever-language programmer". It's a dead end. Be just a programmer instead. And then, SICP is going to be extremely useful. Probably, the most useful reading out there.

Comment: It is a good book for all programmers.

Comment: Ok. So the book seems to be really useful and I'll have to put it on my reading list. But it looks very tough at first look. :(

Comment: It is very tough, that's why you read it.

Comment: little off-topic but since I have decided to read it and considering its complexity what should be the approach to read this book?

Comment: Why do you mention Java three times in your question if the book is not about Java and you don't want to learn Java anyway? I'm puzzled...

Comment: Start at Chapter one, go page by page, work all examples, do not progress until you understand each page and each example. The answer key is online.

Comment: @JonathanHenson and when you get to the end, stop

Comment: and since it uses scheme, do I need to learn scheme before I start reading SICP?

Comment: I'd say no, it starts easy but the learning curve may be steep, so i'd suggest you dive right into it but break if you find your self stuck.

Comment: Yes, you do need to learn Scheme. However, one of the reasons the book uses Scheme is that you can learn the entirety of Scheme in about a day if you have never programmed before or about 10 minutes if you have. After all, SICP is a book for complete beginners, it assumes absolutely no programming knowledge whatsoever.

Comment: Did You Read The Book ? Just Curious

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this book will help you, but when I worked myself through that book about 20 years ago, it definitely improved my programming skills (independently of any programming language). And I guess especially a Java programmer will get some new insights he/she won't get by sticking only to Java.

Joel Spolsky 2005 wrote a nice article about Java and SICP which may be of interest for you:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html

Comment: +1 Best possible answer to what very nearly amounts to a book recommendation question.

Answer (score 13):

I think [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://MITPress.MIT.Edu/sicp/) is a great book to read. However, there are are a couple of problems with it.

The biggest problem in my experience is that, while the book requires absolutely no programming knowledge, and is geared to complete newbies, it *is* geared to complete newbies *who study at MIT*. And so, while it does not assume any programming knowledge, it *does* assume quite a bit of *domain* knowledge, e.g. in the fields of electrical engineering, physics and math. Note: these have nothing to do with the *concepts* being taught, they are just needed to understand the *exercises* and *examples*.

Greater people than me have explained it much better, in a cleverly titled paper [*The Structure and Interpretation of the Computer Science Curriculum*](http://WWW.CCS.NEU.Edu/scheme/pubs/jfp2004-fffk.pdf). Thankfully, they aren't just whiners, they wrote *their own* book instead: [*How to Design Programs*](http://HtDP.Org/). If you think about reading SICP, you might want to read HtDP first: it covers much the same ground as SICP, but it only assumes average high-school level domain knowledge. (In fact, it is written to be taught to high school kids.)

After you have finished HtDP, you can still go back and read SICP, since now some missing bit of domain knowledge won't be as harmful anymore because you have seen the concept before.

Note: there is a [draft for a second edition of HtDP](http://WWW.CCS.NEU.Edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/Draft/), which you might want to read instead of the first edition. The material about imperative programming has been removed, and is going to be covered in the as-of-yet unwritten second volume *How to Design Components*, but you can take those either from the first edition or from SICP or both.

Comment: Might I suggest an alternative to SICP: [Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming](https://smile.amazon.com/Concepts-Techniques-Models-Computer-Programming/dp/0262220695/)

Comment: @Eden: CTM is very good, I agree. I don't think of it as a book for teaching programming, though, like SICP, HtDP, and Concrete Abstractions. But it definitely belongs on the "books that make you a better programmer" list!

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding **SICP**, it is more focused in areas of **functional programming, including recursive programming, and strong introduction to CS** - which is a bit hard to grasp to a new programmers. Another point, it is prepared and instructed in for MIT, and some good fundamentals in engineering field, math, physics is also needed to find this book useful.

I would advice a **good set of books** where each focus on different aspects of software engineering:

- **Code Complete 2** - focuses on the processes of software engineering.
- **Clean Code** - focuses on coding in the small. How to write classes and functions.
- **Pragmatic Programmer** - focuses on working within a team producing software.

More detailed description of mentioned books above and other once can be found from the following references:

1. [How to be a Programmer with 10 Simple Books](http://engtech.wordpress.com/2006/12/04/gift-guide-for-geeks-part-5-tech-books/)
2. [Best books for beginning programmers](http://code.rkevin.com/2009/12/best-books-for-beginning-programmers/)

Please, feel free adding to the list as it is not ideal one :)

**Edit:** In choosing above mentioned books, and determining priority of how to read them, it is really **comes down to the purpose on what you are primary trying to do** or learn.

Comment: I agree with the suggestions in the (implied) context - but your answer would be even better if it actually mentioned what you don't like (or do like) about SICP.

Comment: Apples and oranges comparison - all the books you mention are excellent books about software engineering.  SICP is more about computer science - what computer programming is conceptually.

Comment: This answer feels too much like an answer to a recommended reading list question. Which I do not believe fits well with the aim of the Stack Exchange sites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations/131432#131432

Comment: @Nate, it is not apples and oranges to compare, it is all about CS. Even-though, each of the books share some common topics.

Comment: @MadKeithV, i agree with your comments. I have put my thoughts on SICP in the first line.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say - probably not a good read for most people - whatever language.

Like Knuth it's a good book to have read.  However even assuming you are a hot-shot MIT ugrad it will still take the best part of a year to read properly, and thats with lecturers and TAs helping.

Are there other books on software engineering you could read in that time that would be of more value? Are there other languages you could learn in the time ?

edit Just to expand a little:
Software engineering is engineering, it's all about optimisation. Your task is to maximise your knowledge for a given time+cost budget.
SICP is a high level introduction to programming through a functional language. The reason it uses a functional language is that it's easier to describe a lot of mathematical concepts of programming in functional languages than in procedural ones and a lot easier to read than formal logic.

There is also a certain amount of posturing ie. "You aren't really a programmer unless you read SICP", or Knuth, or can program in Lisp, or C, or x86 assembler. That's normally easy to refute; ie. you can't be a real programmer unless you know Cantor's work on set theory and Maxwell's equations and are familiar with hole mobility in semiconductors.

Comment: There were other books on my wish list like Code Complete 2, Clean code, Pragamatic programmers, Refactoring etc. But these were more on java or at least OOP centric unlike SICP.

Comment: That's why I would read them first

Comment: I debated downvoting this answer, but decided just a comment was better: I agree that SICP is not a good read for most people, especially early on, but I do believe that a great developer should be able to handle this book, and will learn a great deal from it.  Great developers aren't "most people".  It's a good filter book.

Comment: @MadKeithV - but with a finite time available would you be better reading code complete, programming pearls, unix prog environment .... etc

Comment: I disagree (to a point) - a well-rounded developer who has SICP under her belt can always still learn about the Unix environment etc.  I'd rather hire a developer with no platform experience but SICP and retrain them, than someone who doesn't get SICP.

Comment: @MadKeithV - Yes and for the same reason I hire Maths/physics Phds with no coding experience. But if you are working full time as a programmer, and especially a beginner, there are simpler books that are perhaps better (value/time) than Knuth or SICP or reading Turing's papers.

Comment: @MartinBeckett - agreed, starting with SICP is tempting fate ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on being a "JAVA programmer" for the rest of your life? Then there are probably better books to read. If you want to be a good programmer in general then it is an excellent read. Here is why. There are certain tools every good programmer needs in their toolbox. One is a thorough knowledge of data structures and algorithms (if you don't believe me, go interview at Microsoft, Google, Amazon etc...), accompanying algorithms is complexity analysis, recursion, and a sound understanding of pointers doesn't hurt. When it comes to algorithm analysis, recursive processes, and the functional paradigm in general, I can't think of a better or more challenging book than SICP.